# IRI as parameter for filtering ressources

Tags: api, rest, iri

We use IRI for identifying ressource in our API. When we want to filter another ressource with a ressource we have to use the ID part of the IRI. Is that normal?

Exemple :

```
GET /api/authors
[{
  @id: "/api/authors/45gfd654d",
  name: "John Doe",
}]

GET /api/books?authors=[45gfd654d]
```

It seems complicated to use because we have to split the IRI to be able to use the last part in others API calls. My question is : **What are the guidelines in such case? The ressource must have an id (with only the last IRI part) or to we allow to filter with IRI?**

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Indeed a pain! We opted to try and actually use (relative) uris in query parameters.

In many cases we'll also create specialized endpoints like `/api/authors/[id]/books`. Although ultimately similar, our clients don't ever construct or deconstruct urls. Urls are discovered, so a client will find a 'list of books' link on the author resource.

Comment: Yes, specialized endpoints are a good response. But in my case, you can filter the books list by many authors. To avoid calling multiple endpoint you have to filter the books endpoint.